# When making a javascript library, where is a good place to document the API?

Tags: javascript

I am making a library to generate some custom content. It is pretty verbose, about 1100 lines of code. Although the code is very readable and follows strict naming conventions, I am unsure where to document the API available when including the script file. When including the script in a page, intellisense does not pick up the "public" methods, nor does it for jQuery. jQuery has an awesome website for their API ( http://api.jquery.com/ ), but I do not feel inclined to make something as awesome as that.

Where should I document this custom API?

*If* in comments, what structure of comments would you suggest?

*Edit*

My point for intellisense was that even good naming conventions are going to require documented API. So I am definitely interested in a generic approach.

Comment: Please comment if you wish me to add or change something for everyone. Otherwise, please post as an answer so I can award credit.

Comment: Are you just looking for Visual Studio IntelliSense support, or something more generic?

Comment: i think commenting should be done while coding, not after... good luck understanding your code now :s

Comment: Are you putting your library up on github?

Comment: @ajax333221 - The code is fully commented, but should I really make someone wanting to use it dig through all the definitions?

Comment: @kinakuta - No, sorry :(

Comment: No need to apologize - it's just that if you have it up on github there are already some conventions for how you can add documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not generic, but if you didn't mind maintaining separate versions for different editors, Visual Studio's IntelliSense will load and parse XML comments in your JavaScript code. I would suppose MonoDevelop and SharpDevelop could use the same file as well, but I don't think IDEs like IntelliJ or Eclipse would get any use out of it...

HTH.

Comment: I was more thinking of how to show what was available without having to toy or inspect too much. As a side note for your comment about intellisense, vs is really good at this. In your view place an unreachable `if(false){}` block and then inside of it reference the script. Intellisense will automagically do its work (you may have to ctrl shift j to reload).

Comment: I chose this as the answer because it pointed me to commenting in XML comments which is actually rather awesome.

Answer (score 2):

I think jsdoc is pretty popular.

http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/

You would document inline, following the conventions on the link.  You would distribute a minified/obfuscated production build for deployment, and the documented one for development (i.e. you could do that)

Edit, you could also find more options here: http://o2js.com/2011/05/01/how-to-document-a-javascript-framework/

Answer (score 1):

it depends how complex your api is, for my own small libraries i just make a big comment at the top of the file that contains

- a quick writeup of what this is all about
- if the library operates on html markup some example code that can be copy&pasted
- a list of the functions with their parameters and one-line documentation for each
- examples of how the library is typically used
- notes/warnings/limitations. there's always something weird going on people won't expect

basically this is what you'd put in a C header file.

i guess you could do all the things i mentioned above in a separate file and then use markdown syntax (i'm too lazy ... also i prefer having everything in a single file).

---

p.s. some people mention inline-comments (i.e. directly where the functions are). 
this is of course an option too. but to me it seems this is convenient only if have the  docs auto-generated, it is a horrible way to quickly study the documentation inside the file because it lacks a big picture view.